# CPU faulty or Motherboard?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, desktop-computer

My PC in my work Suddenly shut down and didn't boot. We figured that either it's the motherboard or the PSU. After checking the PSU is fine and changing the motherboard, the pc managed to boot (the fans started working), but nothing else, I wasn't even able to get into the bios. The Fans started shutting down and then started again repeatedly without getting to bios. After removing one of the RAM sticks the PC managed to boot to bios so I figured one of the RAM sticks have been damaged with the old motherboard. We changed both RAM sticks with a working pair , and yet the problem persists. It seems like the PC manage to boot with one of the slots only. So my question is this:
Could it be the new motherboard that I got is faulty and one RAM slot doesn't work? Or was it the CPU which got some kind of damage with the old motherboard that now it can't run with two RAM slots?

The PC is pretty old, 4th generation intel processor with DDR3 RAM sticks.

Comment: So you changed the motherboard and used the same processor and had the same or similar problem.  Sounds like your processor is defective.

Comment: Not exactly the same problem. At first the pc didn't boot at all (the fans even didn't start), after changing the motherboard the Fans managed to boot.

Comment: Did you swap the memory sticks from the same kit (between slots) and had the same outcome? If not then it's definitely one of the RAM sticks and not the CPU

Using only 1 stick you should check the BIOS settings for memory to be `safe` or `default`

Comment: I did try to switch between the memory sticks themselves, if I try to boot with 1 stick at the bottom slots it works, if I put the same stick in the upper slot it stops working. My suspicion is that the new motherboard that I got is faulty.

Comment: @mashtock - It's more likely the processor is faulty.